# How to override background image defined in CSS with another CSS?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a 'Core.css' which defines a page background image, along with the theme, for the site. But for a specific page I want to change just the background. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved in a separate CSS file?

The HTML for the page is:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
```

And core.css defines:

```
body
{
        background-image: url('bg.png');
}
```

While index.css defines:

```
body
{
    background-image:('homeBg.png');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it would help to see the css definition on both css files, and how you import them to your webpage.

Comment: is there a missing "url" before '(' in index.css?

Comment: @xorcus looking at it now, yeah it seems "url" is missing...but I couldn't say for sure as this was a long time ago and since forgotten problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

background defined later should replace the previous ones. So if you have:

Site1.css which has:

```
.img {
    background: ...
}
```

Site2.css which has:

```
.img {
    background: ...
}
```

then Site2.css .img would replace .img within Site1.css if Site2.css is included after Site1.css on your page.

UPDATE: I'm not sure why the body tag is not being replaced correctly. Could you try to give it a class or id, and use that instead of body?

e.g.

```
<body id="backgroundTest">
```

And then in the css files you would do `#backgroundTest { background-image... }`

And just in case, could you check if homeBg.png exists and index.css. http://yourpage.com/homeBg.png and http://yourpage.com/index.css should both exist.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it, by using the natural CSS 'cascade'.  Avoid at all costs using the !important declaration as it makes the cascade unpredictable and future maintenance that much harder.

Comment: That's what I thought. The HTML for my code is:

`<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />`

Am i doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Is your css code that should replace the background within the index.css file? Can you show me the css definition where the background is specified for both files. (edit your question)

Comment: @aateeque: Have you checked with a DOM inspector (Firebug or the ones built-in to Chrame or IE) if and in which order the rules are applied?

Comment: @RoToRa how do i do that in CHrome?? Inspect element?

Comment: @RoToRa thanks for the update. Have tried id'ing body but that doesn't work either!

Comment: Check if the file exists in the correct path. index.css and homeBg.png.

Comment: @raRaRa yep...files exist on this path

Comment: @aateeque: In Chrome press "Ctrl-Shift-I". That's the DOM inspector. At the top of it "Elements" should be highlighted with a tree of the HTML code below. Select the `<body ...` element. On the right there is a section titled "Styles" with a subsection "Matched CSS Rules". There your rule should show up on top, with the overridden rule just below.

Comment: @RoToRa thanks so much for your help. It has now resolved - strangely by itself!

Comment: Could it be that the site was cached? Might have been enough to do Ctrl-F5 ? ;)

Answer (score 54):

If you want to replace the background image with nothing (i.e. make it inactive or "turn it off"), use the "none" keyword in your downstream style sheet:

```
 background-image: none;
```

Answer (score 4):

For the specific page you can use a css rule in the page, using [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules). If you add  `your-selector {background: url("the-path-for-the-bg-image") no-repeat !important;}` in the file, will override the default background.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the background in a CSS rule with the same selector as the original rule, and include your new CSS file after the original one, or make sure your new rule has a selector which has a higher specificity: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Finally you could give the background property the `!important` flag, however that is usually a last resort and the sign of a badly organized style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If the page background is set in the body, you can simply overrule it by giving the body in that specific page a class or an id and add (can also be in the same css file...):

```
body.someClass {
  background: ...
}
```

or

```
body#someID {
  background: ...
}
```

(in both the `body` part is not really needed as the class and the id overrule the selector)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What I ended up doing was in my stylesheet which was doing the override, I applied it to not only body, html:

So...

```
#id, html, body { background-color: #FFF }
```

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

in index.css  write

```
 body { background-image:('homeBg.png') !important;
```

you can override any property defined anywhere by writing "!important" after it in new file

Comment: `!important` should not be used in CSS. If forced to use this, its a sign that rules are not applied in the correct order.

Comment: @Hozefa, In current question it is asked how to override css property in new file. My answer is applied for given question , and is not a css uses guideline.

Comment: @Hozefa what if you are dealing with a 3rd party CSS which loads dynamically (you absolutely have no control over the style rules in it) which already has a style defined with a `!important` and you want to overwrite it ??

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Fair point. If the 3rd party CSS loads `!important` then yeah you are left with no choice. Another use case is that when `style` tag is used by JS to add styles.

Comment: @Dashrath With respect to question you are right. But however it could give the impression that its okay to use `!important` as a mechanism to override styles and end up with CSS having `!important` all over the place.