# jQuery 'drop' function is not being called, overridden by 'over' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am dragging the `drag` to `container1` and `container2`.

When it is dropped, `drag` either turns dark purple if in `container1` or dark orange if in `container2`.

When `drag` is passing through `container1`, it should turn green, and when it is passing through `container2`, it should turn yellow (essentially `drag` can change to 4 different colors).

This is what I have, this changes `drag` when it hovers over `container1` and `container2`, but it does not change color when it is dropped.

It seems the `over` function, which handles the hovering, overrides whatever I define my `drop` function to be.

Does anyone know what is going on?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .container {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background: #e9559a;
          padding: 13px;
          margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
        }

        .bdrag {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
          background: grey;
          padding: 5px;
        }

        .dark-purple {
          background: #8b0000;
        }

        .dark-orange {
          background: #000080
        }

        .drop-green {
          background: #38a53a;
        }

        .drop-yellow {
          background: #fbff23;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="shape-container">
              <div id="origin-container" class="container">
                <div id="dragbox" class="bdrag text-dark">
                  <p>Draggable Box</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="dcontainer2" class="container">
                <p>Can drop in here #1</p>
              </div>
              <div id="dcontainer1" class="container">
                <p>Can drop in here #2</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(function() {
            $("#drag-container").draggable({
              revert: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0
                };
                return !event;
              }
            });

            $("#dcontainer1").droppable({
              accept: '#dragbox'
            });

            $("#dcontainer2").droppable({
              accept: '#dragbox'
            });

            $( "#dcontainer2" ).droppable({ 
               over: function() { $("#dragbox").addClass("drop-yellow").removeClass("drop-green"); }, 
<!-- THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT RUN: --!> 
                drop: function() { $("#dragbox").addClass("drop-orange").removeClass("drop-purple").find("p"); } 
            });

            $( "#dcontainer1" ).droppable({ 
               over: function() { $("#dragbox").addClass("drop-green").removeClass("drop-yellow"); }, 
<!-- THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT RUN: --!> 
                drop: function() { $("#dragbox").addClass("drop-purple").removeClass("drop-orange").find("p"); } 
            });

          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is actually a css problem, not a jquery one, [details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805075/how-to-override-background-image-defined-in-css-with-another-css) You're adding both classes at the same time, so you end up with the second background style overriding the first. You'll either need to `.removeClass("drop-orange drop-green drop-yellow")` or just use `.attr("class", "drop-purple")` to replace the whole property

Comment: No probs, you should self-post an answer with a short description and tick it